# How can I do asymmetric encryption and decryption?

Tags: stellar-sdk, keypair

How can I do asymmetric encryption by using Stellar's  private key of sender and Stellar's public key of receiver and vice-versa in case of case decryption? I had gone through many methods but I am not getting what I want.

Comment: There aren't that many options. tweetnacl-box, like, I showed you, does work.
Maybe you can expand on what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah I tried using that but it is not accepting stellar's keypair.

Comment: Of course it doesn't. ed25519 keys are signing keys. They need to be converted to curve25519 keys first. And before that, you need to convert the keys from StrKey encoding to raw binary.

Comment: Yeah I know that but still I am facing problem because the library you suggested was written in js and I am a python developer

Comment: There are python libraries for this also, that's what I used. Years ago though, so I don't remember what they are.

Comment: use pynacl. the SigningKey class has a method for converting to curve25519, which you can then use in Box

Answer (score 1):

Giving full credit to Johan here and mostly just want to have an answer down on this question.

In general, you need to take your Stellar keypair in its raw form (not its StrKey representation), convert it to a `curve25519` key (which is definitely doable with `libsodium` and its various bindings in multiple languages, and take a look at the sealed box encryption provided in `libsodium` and friends.

In Python, you can use PyNaCl to utilize libsodium in Python. Summarizing the exact three steps he mentioned:

1. Take your Stellar keypair and convert it from its StrKey encoding (traditionally `GASOMELONGSETOFCHARACTERS` for a public key) to the raw bytes. It's possible to do this using the Python SDK (take a look at the [KeyPair](https://stellar-base.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#keypair) class, and getting the raw bytes).
2. Because it's an `ed25519` key, you can't encrypt with it. You need to create a key based off of it (in particular, the easiest is to make a `curve25519` key). You can do with `nacl.signing.SigningKey.to_curve25519_private_key` once you've instantiated the `nacl.signing.SigningKey` properly from your bytes (See the [SigningKey](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/signing/#nacl.signing.SigningKey) class. You can see [this public method in the docs](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/nacl/signing/#SigningKey).
3. From there, encrypt using [SealedBox](https://pynacl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public/#nacl-public-sealedbox) in PyNaCl as you see fit.